# Intellj recognizing .wav files as plain text

Tags: intellij-idea, path, wav

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IIvj.png

So I'm trying play a sound everytime a letter is typed on screen. The code is definately correct since I copied it from a reliable source online. The only problem is I keep getting the (The system cannot find the path specified) error. Intellij recognizes .wav files as plain text for some reason. Is there a fix to this? Im I doing something wrong? Nothing I searched for works. Here is the code I use :

```
    private class SoundEffect{
    Clip clip;

    public void setFile(String path) {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(sound);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play(){
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    }
}
```

I am getting the error when I use the setFile method.

Comment: Seems error is not related to detected file type.

Comment: I have no issue with other type of files like png and jpg. So I think it is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.